# simple date validator in RUTA

Tags: apache, uima, ruta

```
DECLARE NUM date;
NUM {REGEXP("[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]") -> CREATE(date)};
INT number = date;
```

> how to do last line of code???

All documentation is here
https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.actions.setfeature

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Assign an integer value to a variable or assign an integer value to a feature of an annotation of the type `date`?

Comment: btw, NUM covers only connected digits

Comment: Can you give an example of the text that should be processed?